# Why first figure in the list is not plotted, but at the end there is an empty plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a problem with matplotlib. 
I need to prepare a plot consisted of all plots from list in specified directory. The code below generating that, but it omits first path...
For example, if I need to prepare image consisted of 14 subplots, only 13 are copied, first is omitted and instead of first, there is an empty plot at the last position.
I have checked, that function reads all paths, including first at list.
If you will be able to help and to give me a hint, what I`m doing wrong, I will be grateful.
Best regards

```
def create_combo_plot(path_to_dir, list_of_png_abspath):
    name = path_to_dir.replace('_out', '')
    title = name
    if name.find('/') != -1:
        title = name.split('/')[-1]
    list_of_png_abspath
    how_many_figures = len(list_)
    combo_figure = plt.figure(2, figsize=(100,100))
    a = 4
    b = int(floor(how_many_figures/4.1)) + 1 
    for i, l in enumerate(list_of_png_abspath):
        print l  #I`ve checked, path is reached
        j = i + 1
        img=mpimg.imread(l)
        imgplot = plt.imshow(img, interpolation="nearest")
        plot = plt.subplot(b, a, j)
    combo_figure.suptitle(title, fontsize=100)
    combo_figure.savefig(path_to_dir +'/' + title + '.jpeg')
    plt.close(combo_figure)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace these two lines:

```
imgplot = plt.imshow(img, interpolation="nearest")
plot = plt.subplot(b, a, j)
```

with these:

```
sub = plt.subplot(b, a, j)
sub.imshow(img, interpolation="nearest")
```

The line:

```
imgplot = plt.imshow(img, interpolation="nearest")
```

adds a new plot to the last active subplot. In your case it was created in the previous loop here:

```
plot = plt.subplot(b, a, j)
```

Therefore, you start with the second image and the last subplot stays empty.

But if you create the subplot first:

```
sub = plt.subplot(b, a, j)
```

and later explicitly plot into it:

```
sub.imshow(img, interpolation="nearest")
```

you should see 14 plots.